# Animate Spring Pendelum

Tags: scoping

Is there ANYBODY who can solve this exercise???

Visualize the oscillation of a spring pendulum . Write to a function ( modules ) "spring mass" [ eg , nzigzag ] , which visualizes the spring ( Line ) and the oscillating mass ( Rectangle ) for a given total length z and a number of spring coils ( nzigzag ).
In Combination with

```
Animate
[Graphics[springmass[5+Sin[\[Phi]],23],
PlotRange->{-9,0}],{\[Phi],0,2\[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Thanks for helping!

---

This ist the code which i've written, but it does't work!

```
springmass[a0_, x10_, x20_] := 
  Module[{a = a0, x1 = x10, x2 = x20, n = 100}, h = (x2 - x1)/n;
   xwerte = Table[k, {k, x1, x2, h}];
   ywerte = Table[a Sin[m Pi/2], {m, 0, n}];
   Line[Transpose@{xwerte, ywerte}]];

springmass[a0_, y10_, y20_] := 
  Module[{a = a0, y1 = y10, y2 = y20, n = 100}, h = (y2 - y1)/n;
   ywerte = Table[k, {k, y1, y2, h}];
   xwerte = Table[a Sin[m Pi/2], {m, 0, n}];
   Line[Transpose@{xwerte, ywerte}]];

Animate[Graphics[springmass[5 + Sin[\[Phi]], 23],
  PlotRange -> {-9, 0}], {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

> ```
> Transpose::nmtx: "The first two levels of {{0},{0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,0.`,-0.2`,0.`,0.2`,<<51>>}} cannot be transposed. 
>
> Coordinate Transpose[{{0}, {0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2, 0., -0.2, 0., 0.2,  should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.
> ```

Comment: One problem is that you are calling `springmass` with 2 arguments, but you've defined it to need 3 arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
Animate[Show[
ParametricPlot3D[{0.5 Sin[q], 0.5 Cos[q], 50 - (0.1 + Sin[t Pi]^2) q},
{q, 0, 50}, Axes -> False, PlotRange ->{All, All,{-10, 50}},BoxRatios->{1, 1, 10}],
Graphics3D[Cuboid[{-0.5, -0.5, 50-(0.1 + Sin[t Pi]^2) 50}]]] 
,{t,0, 4}]
```

Comment: put that in z coordinate and modify the `PlotRange` accorgdingly.

Comment: First thing you should do is read the documentation and see how to write the codes. Otherwise copy paste wouldn't make any sense. Regarding the above piece of code it is `Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[q], Cos[q], 5 + Sin[t] q}, {q, 0, 50},  Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {All, All, {-50, 50}}], {t, 0, 20}]`